# iPhone app response to a push message immediately

Tags: iphone

i wish for my app to start doing something in the background as soon as a push message is received, rather than when the person clicks the "view" button on the modal.
is this possible? and if not, is there anyway to get an app to register to listen to anything else even if it is my own server connection, even when the app isn't running in the background?
I notice google latitude somehow seems to send gps updates even when it is not running in the background?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if your application is not continuously running in the background and then I don't mean that it's pushed to the background but it has to remain active with the three background modes you can setup. These are audio (red bar in top when then app is placed in the background), voip and geo location. So by playing with these three modes you can keep the application continuously running.

But you are also able to reconize if there has been a local push notification if the app is re-opened again.

Comment: Assuming I could make it stay running all the time, and maintain a persistent COMET style connection to my server, is it possible for this state to be entered into without the user initially running the app? ie after a reboot of the phone or after installation of the app?

Comment: No this is not possible. The user always has to active the application first before it's able to run.